# Regex to match character unless it is preceded by an odd number of another specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

Another way to state my problem is to match a character always when it is preceded by an even number (0, 2, 4, ...) of another specific character.

In my case I want to match all `'` characters in string unless it is preceded by an odd number (1, 3, 5 ...) of `?`

example:

```
- ?' => shouldn't match (preceded by one ?)
- ??' => Should match (preceded by 2 ?)
- ?????' => Shouldn't match (preceded by 5 ?)
```

Lets consider this scenario:

We have this string : `' ??' ????' ?' ??????'` then the regex should match all `'` characters in this case except for the 4th one, so for example if I want to use String.split(regex) the result would be ['', '??', '????', ?' '??????']

Currently I was using this regex: `(?<!\?)'`, but the problem is that it matches only if there is no `?` before `'`

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: @decpk lets consider this string : `' ??' ????' ??????'`  then the regex should match all `'` characters in this case
so for example if I want to use String.split(regex) the result would be ['', '??', '????', '??????']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?)*)'/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2ch1W/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?)*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is preceded with any zero or more occurrences of double `?` not immediately preceded with another `?`
- `'` - a `'` char.

Sample code:

```js
const texts = ["The ?' should not match","The ??' should match","?????' => The ?????' should not match"];
const rx = /(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?)*)'/g
for (var text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', rx.test(text));
}
```

If you need replacing, it is possible with

```js
const texts = ["The ?' should not match","The ??' should match","?????' => The ?????' should not match"];
const rx = /(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?)*)'/g
for (var text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.replace(rx, '<MATCH>$&</MATCH>'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a lookbehind condition:

```sh
(?<=([^?]|^)(?:\?\?)*)'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XWEbX2/3)

**RegEx Explanation**

- `(?<=`: Start lookbehind condition

  - `([^?]|^)`: Match a non-`?` character or start
  - `(?:\?\?)*`: Match 0 or more pairs of `?`
- `)`: End lookbehind condition
- `'`: Match a `'`